# Why does using "explicit wait" inside a frame produce a timeout error, but using "time.sleep" works?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

This code works:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# Define browser
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r"path\geckodriver.exe")

# Open website
browser.get('website')

# Get "before" window handle
window_before = browser.window_handles[0]

# Login
searchElem = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#login')
searchElem.send_keys('login')
searchElem2 = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#password')
searchElem2.send_keys('password')
searchElem2.submit()

# Next page loads
time.sleep(2)
browser.switch_to.frame(3)
searchElem3 = browser.find_element_by_name('Element')
searchElem3.click()
searchElem3.send_keys('Hello')
searchElem3.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

But I have read that it is more efficient to use "explicit wait" instead of "time.sleep" so I tried this, but this code throws the TimeoutExceptionError:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# Define browser
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r"path\geckodriver.exe")

# Open website
browser.get('website')

# Get "before" window handle
window_before = browser.window_handles[0]

# Login
searchElem = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#login')
searchElem.send_keys('login')
searchElem2 = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#password')
searchElem2.send_keys('password')
searchElem2.submit()

# Next page loads
try:
    searchElem3 = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(By.ID, "Element"))
finally:
    browser.quit()
searchElem3.click()
searchElem3.send_keys('Hello')
searchElem3.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? I have also tried multiple ways to locate the element to no avail (instead of By.ID, using XPATH, etc)

EDIT: Just to clarify, "frame(3)" and "Element" are the same frame, the one I am trying to switch to. What I was trying to do with the second attempt is to use "webdriverwait" instead of "time.sleep"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because in your 2nd attempt you are not switching to the frame before waiting for the element. Selenium waited for the 10 seconds for the element on the parent window and could not find it on the parent window. Hence failing with timeout.

But in your 1st approach you are switching to the frame usig `browser.switch_to.frame(3)` and selenium is able to find the element in the 3rd frame successfully.

Try adding the explicit wait on the 3rd frame.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear, the ID "Element" and frame (3) are the same frame. So instead of doing "time.sleep" to wait for this frame, I was trying to use an "explicit wait" instead. I used the "Element" because it would throw a "bool" error whenever I used "3" or "frame(3)"

Comment: I tried it anyway, and it threw this error: "TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given"

Comment: change it to ` searchElem3 = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "Element")))`

Comment: I tried it with the extra brackets, and threw the TimeoutExceptionError. So I guess the issue is that when the "Submit" button is pressed at: ```searchElem2.submit()``` that the next window loads but the program is waiting for the "Element" frame to be available on the previous window? Is that right? So before waiting for the frame should I be telling it to wait for a specific window? I'm not sure how to do this.